# Debug BlackBerry App SSL Certificate Problems

Tags: blackberry, ssl, ssl-certificate, blackberry-eclipse-plugin

We are testing a BlackBerry app that accesses a secure RESTful service.

One of our customers is getting an "Access Denied: Insecure SSL Request" error when trying to access our web service. The customer device is running OS6. We have not been able to reproduce this with an OS6 simulator. The cert is installed on the simulator that matches his device.

We have seen similar cert problems with OS5 devices and simulators. We are using a Root Level Certificate (Thawte Primary CA) that is not installed on BlackBerry OS5. We have been able to solve similar problems on the OS5 devices by manually installing the certificate.

The manual cert install fix works for accessing the service from the OS6 devices' browser, but we get a "Access Denied: Insecure SSL Request" error when trying a https operation from our app. We are not able to reproduce this on any of our devices.

Questions:

1. Does the "Access Denied: Insecure SSL Request" error indicate the customer's device isusing the BlackBerry Enterprise Server? All google results for this error indicate the BES.
2. This cert has a wildcard that points to our many sub-domains. Could switching to a cert that explicitly points to the problem domain solve this? We recently changed our certs, but they work fine on iOS, Android, IE, FireFox & Chrome.
3. Any there any code changes we can make to fix this? We are creating the connection using the HttpsConnection. We are developing using the Java 5.0 libaray.
4. What other steps would you recommend for trying to track down this problem?

Comment: Check that the device has the correct date and time set.  Certificates have a start and end date for validity, and being outside of that valid timespan means the cert won't work.